# TYPO3 : no updated newsletter with direct_mail and scheduler

Tags: typo3, newsletter

*This is my 1st question on this forum... So, please, be indulgent !*

I'm using **TYPO3 4.7.11** (PHP 5.3.3) with extension **direct_mail 3.1.1** for the intranet site of a non-profit firm.

My problem (maybe connected to Bug #51583 : http://forge.typo3.org/issues/51583) is that, after numerous tests and attempts, it seems impossible to have an updated version of a page saved as draft for newsletter in an automatic scheduler driven way : the same newsletter is produced with the same informations that were already there on the day it was first created and saved.

The specific page used for newsletter includes a content element 'Menu/Sitemap' with 'Recently updated pages' as 'Menu type'. It has been saved as 'draft (for recurring sendings)' in Direct Mail.

The scheduler contains these 2 tasks with recurring type :

```
- Direct Mail: Create Mail from Draft (direct_mail)
- Direct Mail: Mailing Queue (direct_mail)
```

*Note : the manual way is fully functional and the newsletter produced is really updated. Same with option "Testmail - Simple" !*

So, my problem seems to be linked to the automatic scheduled mailing ! It looks as if the newsletter draft has turned into a freezed snapshot of a specific moment and that Typo3 is unable to update/recalculate this page when invoked in scheduler mode.

On the web, I saw reported problems that could be related like "When mails get sent via the scheduler the same subject is used for all sendings ( https://review.typo3.org/21313 )" and "Adding hooks when sending direct mails via scheduler (   forge.typo3.org/issues/48994  )", but these issues seem to be fixed with direct_mail 3.1.1 version.

I made these observations and, in my opinion, there is some relevancy :

1.There is no domain proposed in the 'Domain of internal links' drop-down list in 'Set default values for mail content fetching options' in Direct Mailer, and yet I have a single record in **sys_domain** table with a domain name (with no protocol and no final slash). Is there a reason why this record is not considered good, or isn't it the right table ? (uid=3, pid, tstamp, crdate, cruser_id, hidden, sorting, prepend_params and forced=0, redirectHttpStatusCode=301, domain_name=site.subdomain.domain, redirectTo=)

2.In the Typo 3 Log, I get this systematic error message for user **_cli_scheduler@LIVE** :

> Core: Error handler (BE): PHP Warning: Invalid argument supplied for
>   foreach() in
>   ...typo3conf/ext/direct_mail/Classes/Scheduler/MailFromDraft.php line
>   125.

The concerned part of MailFromDraft.php is this function : initializeHookObjects

...
      /*

```
  * Initializes hook objects for this class

  *

  * @return    void

  */

 function initializeHookObjects() {

     foreach ($GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['direct_mail']['mailFromDraft'] as $hookObj) {

         $hookObjectInstance = t3lib_div::getUserObj($hookObj);

         if (is_object($hookObjectInstance) && ($hookObjectInstance instanceof x_directmail_Scheduler_MailFromDraftHook)) {

             $this->hookObjects[] = $hookObjectInstance;

         }

     }

 }

 ...
```

I'm not sure of understanding very clearly the origin and the use of the hook Object... (in spite of this interesting article by Robert Lemke : typo3.org/documentation/article/how-to-use-existing-hooks-in-your-own-extension/ )

3.Nothing like the apparently requested **GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['direct_mail']['mailFromDraft']**  seems to exist in TYPO3_CONF_VARS (Global configuration).

Can anybody give me an advice or a clue about what's going on and why I can't get a weekly updated newsletter with the scheduler ? I feel a bit confused !

Thanks in advance for any suggestion or solution (if a miracle is possible).

Greetings.

P-H SILLIAU

Answer (score 0):

I've read about this issue before, but couldn't remember where.
Googling "direct_mail draft (for recurring sendings)" helped.

Try this bug: http://forge.typo3.org/issues/4421

User Markus says:

> Things work fine, when you set a domain-record in your system and
>   select it in the direct_mail settings!
>
> If you don't have a domain-record and specify it in the direct_mail
>   setup you're able to send normal newsletters, but if you try the
>   draft-functionality  it won't work because the getUrlBase function in
>   class.tx_directmail_static.php returns an unsuable URL to the System
>   so it can't use the fetchHTML($file) and quits - therefore not
>   replacing the old draft contents created when starting the first time.
>
> I don't really get why this works the first time you set up the draft
>   though....
>
> So setting up the domain-record is a work-around that works.

I hope it does!

Probably, you will find more related topics.

Else, workarounds would be

- re-considering the task. As it's a NPO intranet, maybe requirements are not that required suddenly, if asked again :-)
- setting up a custom notification tool that only does that precise job.

Comment: Hi Markus There is a more recent bug on the same subject [link](http://forge.typo3.org/issues/27274) **bold** `Draft Mode sending the same Mail - not the new Version`

Comment: Hi Markus
There is a more recent bug on the same subject : [link](http://forge.typo3.org/issues/27274) **Draft Mode sending the same Mail - not the new Version**

I'm fully aware of the necessity of setting a domain-record. The point is I have one record in sys_domain table, but I can't choose it in the drop-down list 'Domain of internal links' of Direct-Mail settings because the list is empty. How can I force that ?
P-H Silliau

Comment: Markus is an user on the forge. Anyway, this is very specific. Try push these issues on forge and maybe get in touch with the developers.

Comment: Hi Urs.
In parallel of this site, I contacted the main developer of direct_mail extension in order to get some specific advice.
I still estimate that some people in the community of Typo3 users might have experienced the same problem and found a solution or a workaround : this problem can be resumed to a simple non-refresh issue.

Answer (score 0):

To put an end to this problem, after many attempts (and informations gleaned from the internet), here is the solution we finally used in our specific case to make the newsletter work :

1st. We created a record in table **sys_domain**. This was a recurrent instruction in the manual and the forums, and it was IMHO legitimate.

Important : note that the **redirectTo** field had to remain empty, due to global malfunction of the site if filled (whatever we put in it like /, /var/www/sitename, ...)

2nd. All images, CSS, JS included in template had to be hardcoded (i.e. http ://site/fileamin/images/xxx.png for instance). If we didn't do that, the result would have been an abort in the production of the newletter : Not Found... Maybe, by digging a bit deeper, should we be able to find a parameter we forgot or neglected in some way to solve this issue...

3rd. In the newsletter template TS setup, we added these 2 parameters :

- **mod.web_modules.dmail.use_domain=*[uid of sys-domain]***
- **config.absRefPrefix = /**    (in order to get rid of PHP DOCUMENT_ROOT (or TYPO3_DOCUMENT_ROOT ?) otherwise wrongly present in all generated links.)

The result is now a well dynamically-generated newsletter, the date is OK, all links are correct and **realUrl**-compliant (no ../index.php?id=nnn) .... and you know what ?... We're happy ! :-)

*Hope it will help !*

Many thanks to everybody who answered (Markus, Urs...) or even thought of a possible solution...

P-H Silliau